# Flink keyed stream key is null

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am trying to perform a map operation on a KeyedStream in Flink:

```
stream.map(new JsonToMessageObjectMapper())
                    .keyBy("keyfield")
                    .map(new MessageProcessorStateful())
```

The output of the JsonToObjectMapper operator is a POJO of class **MessageObject** which has a String field '**keyfield**'. The stream is then keyed on this field.

The MessageProcessorStateful is a RichMapFunction like this:

```
public class MessageAdProcessorStateful extends RichMapFunction<MessageObject, Tuple2<String, String>> {

    private transient MapState<String, Tuple2<Tuple3<String, String, String>, Tuple2<Double, Long>>> state;
    ...
    @Override
    public void open(Configuration config) throws Exception {
        MapStateDescriptor<String, Tuple2<Tuple3<String, String, String>, Tuple2<Double, Long>>> descriptor =
                    new MapStateDescriptor<>(
                        "state",                                                                                     // the state name
                            TypeInformation.of(new TypeHint<String>() {}),
                            TypeInformation.of(new TypeHint<Tuple2<Tuple3<String, String, String>, Tuple2<Double, Long>>>() {}) ); // type information
                    state = getRuntimeContext().getMapState(descriptor);

        state.put(...); // Insert a key, value here. Exception here!

    }
}
```

The code throws a NullPointer exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: No key set. This method should not be called outside of a keyed context.
    at org.apache.flink.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:75)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.heap.CopyOnWriteStateTable.checkKeyNamespacePreconditions(CopyOnWriteStateTable.java:528)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.heap.CopyOnWriteStateTable.computeHashForOperationAndDoIncrementalRehash(CopyOnWriteStateTable.java:722)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.heap.CopyOnWriteStateTable.get(CopyOnWriteStateTable.java:265)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.heap.CopyOnWriteStateTable.get(CopyOnWriteStateTable.java:306)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.heap.HeapMapState.put(HeapMapState.java:75)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.UserFacingMapState.put(UserFacingMapState.java:52)
    at org.myorg.quickstart.MessageStreamProcessor$MessageAdProcessorStateful.open(MessageStreamProcessor.java:226)
    at org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.util.FunctionUtils.openFunction(FunctionUtils.java:36)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractUdfStreamOperator.open(AbstractUdfStreamOperator.java:102)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.openAllOperators(StreamTask.java:393)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:254)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:718)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Seems the key in the keyedState for one of the KeyedStream is null although I have verified that the 'keyfield' is always a valid string. Rest seems to be correct as per the Flink documentation. Any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem is that you try to access the keyed state in the `open()` method.

Keyed state maintains a state instance for each key. In your example you are using `MapState`. So you have one `MapState` instance for each key. When accessing the state, you'll always get the state instance that corresponds to the key of the currently processed record. In a `MapFunction` (like in your example) this would be the record that is passed to the `map()` method.

Since `open()` is not called with a record, the current key in `open()` is `null` and it is not possible to access the keyed state.

Comment: is it possible to save some state and work with it in `open` method? I mean, I have a global state for a function that is not accociated to any keys and events. Are there any workarounds for this limitations?

Comment: Yes, there is operator state in Flink. However, you should be aware that operator state can be redistributed if the job is rescaled or recovers from a failure. See the docs for details: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/state/state.html#using-operator-state

Answer (score 0):

Another casue of this may be accessing or modifying keyed state in `processBroadcastElement()` function:

```
  @Override
  public void processBroadcastElement(Rule Rule, Context ctx, Collector<Object> out)
      throws Exception {
      state.put(Rule.id, Rule);
  }
```

In this case, you can use `applyToKeyedState()` function to [register KeyedStateFunction to be applied to all states of all keys associated with the provided stateDescriptor](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/dev/datastream/fault-tolerance/broadcast_state/#:%7E:text=KeyedStateFunction%20to%20be%20applied%20to%20all%20states%20of%20all%20keys%20associated%20with%20the%20provided%20stateDescriptor).