# Initialize the content of a MapState

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have implemented a Flink `RichFunction` that have the following structure :

```
public class MyFunction extends KeyedBroadcastProcessFunction <String, InputType, BroadcastedStateType, OutputType> {

    private MapState<String, MyState> myState;              

    @Override
    public void open(Configuration conf)throws Exception{
        myState = getRuntimeContext().getMapState(new MapStateDescriptor<>("state", Types.STRING, Types.POJO(BroadcastedStateType.class)));
    }

    @Override
    public void processElement(InputType value, ReadOnlyContext ctx, Collector<OutputType> out) throws Exception {
        MyState state = myState.get(value.ID());

        // Do things
    }

    @Override
    public void processBroadcastElement(BroadcastedStateType value, Context ctx, Collector<OutputType> out) throws Exception {
        state.put(value.ID(), value.state());   // Update the mapState with value from broadcast
    }

    // retrieve all the state values and put them in the MapState
    private void initialState() throws Exception{
       Map<String, MyState> initialValues = ...;
       this.cameras.putAll(initialValues);
    }
}
```

The `mapState` variable store multiple states that are updated via a `BroadcastedStream`. The update is done in the `processBroadcastElement()` function.

At the start of the job, I want to initialize the `mapState` by using the `initialState()` function.

The problem is that I cannot use it in the `open()` function (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48555816/flink-keyed-stream-key-is-null) why)

What is the correct way to initialize the `mapState` in this case ? (And in all cases with RichFunctions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to implement org.apache.flink.streaming.api.checkpoint.CheckpointedFunction

When you do that, you implement two methods:

```
@Override
public void snapshotState(FunctionSnapshotContext context) throws Exception {

    // called when it's time to save state

    myState.clear();

        // Update myState with current application state 

}

@Override
public void initializeState(FunctionInitializationContext context) throws Exception {

    // called when things start up, possibly recovering from an error

    descriptor = new MapStateDescriptor<>("state", Types.STRING, Types.POJO(BroadcastedStateType.class));

    myState = context.getKeyedStateStore().getMapState(descriptor);

    if (context.isRestored()) {

        // restore application state from myState  

    }       

}
```

You initialize your myState variable in the initializeState() method instead of open().

Comment: @nakeuh did that answer your question? My interpretation of what you said was that you were looking where you could call the `initialState()` method you defined without Flink throwing the exception in question. If my interpretation is correct, this answer is wrong because calling `myState.put(...)` inside `initializeState` will throw the same exception as when you call it inside `open`

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can actually initialize broadcast state in initializeState(). The only way to modify broadcast state is via the read/write context you get in the processBroadcastElement method.

But what you could do is to use context.isRestored() in initializeState to determine if the KeyedBroadcastProcessFunction is being initialized for the very first time, and set a transient local variable to record this information. And then the first time the processBroadcastElement method is called you can use this information to decide what to store in the broadcast state. But you will have to send something on the broadcast stream to kick this off.

Comment: What I did actually is just initializing 'normal' Java Map inside `open()`. In `snapshotState()`, I fill my `MapState` with the content of my Java Map, and in `initializeState()`, if `context.isRestored()`, I fill my Java Map from my `MapState`