# How to enrich event stream with big file in Apache Flink?

Tags: scala, csv, apache-flink

I have a Flink application for click stream collection and processing. The application consists of Kafka as event source, a map function and a sink as image shown below:

[image: Flink, huge, static enrichment data]

I want to enrich the incoming click stream data with user's IP location based on userIp field in raw event ingested from Kafka.

a simplified slice of the CSV file as shown below

```
   start_ip,end_ip,country
   "1.1.1.1","100.100.100.100","United States of America"
   "100.100.100.101","200.200.200.200","China"
```

I have made some researches and found a couple of potential solutions:

**1. Solution:** Broadcast the enrichment data and connect with event stream with some IP matching logic.

**1. Result:** It worked well for a couple sample IP location data but not with whole CSV data. JVM heap has reached to 3.5 GB and due to the broadcast state, there is no way to put the broadcast state into disk (for RocksDb)

**2. Solution:** Load CSV data in `open()` method in `RichFlatMapFunction` into the state(ValueState) before start of the event processing and enrich event data in `flatMap` method.

**2. Result:** Due to the enrichment data is so big to store in JVM heap, it's impossible to load into ValueState. And also de/serializing through ValueState is bad practice for data in key-value nature.

**3. Solution:** To avoid to deal with JVM heap constraint, I have tried to put the enrichment data into RocksDB(uses disk) as state with MapState.

**3. Result:** Trying to load the CSV file into MapState in `open()` method, gave me error that tells me you cannot put into MapState in `open()` method because I was not in keyed context in `open()` method like this question: [Flink keyed stream key is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48555816/flink-keyed-stream-key-is-null)

**4. Solution:** Because of need of the keyed context for MapState(to put RocksDB), I tried to load whole CSV file into local RocksDB instance(disk) in the process function after making the DataStream into KeyedStream:

```
class KeyedIpProcess extends KeyedProcessFunction[Long, Event, Event] {

  var ipMapState: MapState[String, String] = _
  var csvFinishedFlag: ValueState[Boolean] = _

  override def processElement(event: Event,
                              ctx: KeyedProcessFunction[Long, Event, Event]#Context,
                              out: Collector[Event]): Unit = {

    val ipDescriptor = new MapStateDescriptor[String, String]("ipMapState", classOf[String], classOf[String])
    val csvFinishedDescriptor = new ValueStateDescriptor[Boolean]("csvFinished", classOf[Boolean])

    ipMapState = getRuntimeContext.getMapState(ipDescriptor)
    csvFinishedFlag = getRuntimeContext.getState(csvFinishedDescriptor)

    if (!csvFinishedFlag.value()) {
      val csv = new CSVParser(defaultCSVFormat)

      val fileSource = Source.fromFile("/tmp/ip.csv", "UTF-8")
      for (row <- fileSource.getLines()) {
        val Some(List(start, end, country)) = csv.parseLine(row)
        ipMapState.put(start, country)
      }
      fileSource.close()
      csvFinishedFlag.update(true)
    }

    out.collect {
      if (ipMapState.contains(event.userIp)) {
        val details = ipMapState.get(event.userIp)
        event.copy(data =
          event.data.copy(
            ipLocation = Some(details.country)
          ))
      } else {
        event
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**4. Result:** It's too hacky and prevents event processing due to blocking file read operation.

Could you tell me what can I do for this situation?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to implement a custom partitioner, and load a slice of the enrichment data into each partition. There's an example of this approach [here](https://github.com/knaufk/enrichments-with-flink/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/knaufk/enrichments/CustomPartitionEnrichmenttJob.java); I'll excerpt some key portions:

The job is organized like this:

```java
DataStream<SensorMeasurement> measurements = env.addSource(new SensorMeasurementSource(100_000));

DataStream<EnrichedMeasurements> enrichedMeasurements = measurements
  .partitionCustom(new SensorIdPartitioner(), measurement -> measurement.getSensorId())
  .flatMap(new EnrichmentFunctionWithPartitionedPreloading());
```

The custom partitioner needs to know how many partitions there are, and deterministically assigns each event to a specific partition:

```java
private static class SensorIdPartitioner implements Partitioner<Long> {
    @Override
    public int partition(final Long sensorMeasurement, final int numPartitions) {
        return Math.toIntExact(sensorMeasurement % numPartitions);
    }
}
```

And then the enrichment function takes advantage of knowing how the partitioning was done to load only the relevant slice into each instance:

```java
public class EnrichmentFunctionWithPartitionedPreloading extends RichFlatMapFunction<SensorMeasurement, EnrichedMeasurements> {

    private Map<Long, SensorReferenceData> referenceData;

    @Override
    public void open(final Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
        super.open(parameters);
        referenceData = loadReferenceData(getRuntimeContext().getIndexOfThisSubtask(), getRuntimeContext().getNumberOfParallelSubtasks());
    }


    @Override
    public void flatMap(
            final SensorMeasurement sensorMeasurement,
            final Collector<EnrichedMeasurements> collector) throws Exception {
        SensorReferenceData sensorReferenceData = referenceData.get(sensorMeasurement.getSensorId());
        collector.collect(new EnrichedMeasurements(sensorMeasurement, sensorReferenceData));
    }

    private Map<Long, SensorReferenceData> loadReferenceData(
            final int partition,
            final int numPartitions) {
        SensorReferenceDataClient client = new SensorReferenceDataClient();
        return client.getSensorReferenceDataForPartition(partition, numPartitions);
    }

}
```

Note that the enrichment is *not* being done on a keyed stream, so you can not use keyed state or timers in the enrichment function.