# How can I initialize keyed state with initial values in Apache Flink?

Tags: apache-flink

I want to initialize `MapState` in a `KeyedStream` in Apache Flink with some initial values as shown in the code snipit at the bottom of the post. Unfortunately, Flink does not let you do this in the `open` method, as explained here: [Flink keyed stream key is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48555816/flink-keyed-stream-key-is-null). As the post I referenced was from 2020, I am hoping something may have changed since then.

The initial values that I wish to put in the MapState would be the same for all keys.

**What I have tried**

- Overriding the `initializeState` function in `org.apache.flink.streaming.api.checkpoint.CheckpointedFunction` and adding the `myState.put(...)` stuff in there, but this gets the same exception as doing this in the `open` method
- This post mentions to use `OperatorState`, but I don't think this works for my use-case: [Flink keyed stream key is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48555816/flink-keyed-stream-key-is-null)

I realize I can do something like `if (myState.isEmpty()) { addInitialStateToMyState() }` inside of `processElement`, but hoping to avoid this

```
new KeyedProcessFunction<String, Row, String>()  {
            MapState<String,String> myState;

            @Override
            public void processElement(final Row event, final KeyedProcessFunction<String, Row, String>.Context context, final Collector<String> collector) throws Exception {
               ...
               myState.put("this", "works")
               ...
            }

            @Override
            public void open(Configuration configuration) throws Exception {
                MapStateDescriptor<> myStateDescriptor = new MapStateDescriptor<>(
                        "my-state",
                        String.class,
                        String.class
                );
                myState = getRuntimeContext().getMapState(myStateDescriptor);

                // can't initialize here; can only do this inside `processElement`
                myState.put("this", "fails");
            }
```

Thanks for any help/insights!

Comment: Why do you need to initialize the state?

Comment: I am doing counts of events (where all the events are bounded and known ahead of time). Being able to initialize the counts of all my events to 0 lets me avoid having to check if a key exists in my MapState before updating it.

Comment: If you really worry about this, have another ValueState<Boolean>, and if that's not set then initialize your map state with the pre-defined set of keys. Or have a transient boolean, and use that but realize it might be false even though you have an initialized MapState

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, I don't think there is a way to do this in a prettier way. All access to keyed state must be done in a key aware fashion, which means it needs to be done in `processElement`. Operator state is generally more complex, so if the only reason for picking it would be to code cleanliness I'd avoid it.